# Calling methods in qml - javascript from c++. Scope problem

Tags: javascript, c++, qml, qt-quick

I want to call a method in qml - javascript from c++.
Basically I think that I have done everything that is said in documentation. 
I can call the method if it is like this:

```
Rectangle {
......
    Component.onCompleted:{
    ...........
    }

    function foo(arg1, arg2)
    {
        ................
    }
}
```

But I can't call the same function if I put it like this and in a separate .js file it like this:

```
import ../Script.js as Script
Rectangle {
    .........

    Component.onCompleted:{
       Script.foo(arg1,arg2)
    }

}
```

The script is imported and everything, but I still have a problem that says that the arguments are not recognized. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are arg1 and arg2 defined somewhere in your Rectangle?

Else it should work, except that you have to import the Script.js with quotation marks

```
import "../Script.js" as Script
```

For testing I used

Script.js

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    print(arg1, arg2)
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

import "Script.js" as Script

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Script.foo("a", "b");
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not defined anywhere in Rectangle. Because in the first case everything is working ok. But not in the second case.
So what should I do, should I declare them somewhere. In the example that you are giving me you are just sending two strings to the function, what I want to do is to invoke the method from c++ with different type of variables. 
And when I do that I get
"QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QDeclarativeRectangle::foo2(QVariant,QVariant)" error

And about the quotation marks, I know that I just forgot to put them in the code example before